# RebEx Select All Except Starting With Asterik

Tags: regex

I have a list of displays that I wish to group via a regex but ignore anything that begins with an asterik (*). In other words it would select `DISPLAY1` and `DISPLAY2` but ignore `*DISPLAY3`. I was thinking something like `[^*].*` but that doesn't work. Anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It deleted my first asterik and I didn't see where I could edit my post. I meant [^*].* ... if this doesn't display right, I mean [^asterisk].*

Comment: If it is supported, try a negative lookbehind `(?<!\*)DISPLAY\d+` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e7t9DX/1/)

Comment: No, that did not work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using? Are the words part of a sentence?

Comment: It would be php. It's a digital signage software package called Xibo. You use regular expressions to group your displays. They displays can be named anything, and I want to select all of them except a display which begins with an *. If I use (^\*).* I get only displays which begin with an *. How do I say do the opposite of that?

Comment: Try it like this with a negative lookahead `^(?!\*)DISPLAY\d+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAXgr0/1) or `^(?!\*).+`[demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdNOqG/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to anchor your pattern to the start of the string:

```
^[^*].+
```